# Unity (C#) - Script on network manager disabled on scene change even with dontdestroyonload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I added a script called "HostGame" to my Network Manager and when the "Create Lobby" button is pressed, "HostGame" triggers a function that starts a matchmaking match. When I press the leave game button, a different script disconnects me from the match and the game changes back to the lobby scene as it should, however the create lobby button has lost its reference to the host game script even though the Network Manager never went away.

I added an "OnDisable" event to "HostGame" which wrote to the console when it was disabled and it was the moment I pressed leave game where "HostGame" was disabled.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Scenes cause a lot of headaches because data isn't *supposed* to persist across them and doing the things that keep objects loaded introduce their own headaches. Make sure that your Netowrk Manager isn't being duplicated (or ovewriting the existing instance's data trying to instantiate).

Comment: I've just got the networkmanager script that unity gives as a component added to an empty gameobject called _NETMANAGER_ and for some reason it keeps everything the same when switching from the lobby to the game but when leaving the game and returning back to the lobby, the HostGame script attached to the networkmanager object turns into one of those blank scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you have the NetworkManager on a GameObject `N` in the Lobby scene, with its `Dont Destroy On Load` property set.
Also, you have another GameObject `R` in the scene which references `N`.

Now this happens:

- Game Starts
- You are in "Lobby.scene"
- On Login

  - Everything in "Lobby.scene" except GameObject `N` (because of DontDestroyOnLoad) is destroyed.
  - NetworkManager loads scene "Game.scene"
- Game runs for a while
- On Logout

  - Everything in "Game.scene" except `N` (because of DontDestroyOnLoad) is destroyed.
  - NetworkManager loads scene "Lobby.scene"
  - You now have 2 GameObjects `N` #1 and `N` #2 with a NetworkManager, as the original was never destroyed, but you also loaded a new instance from "Lobby.scene"
  - `R` was loaded from "Lobby.scene" and references `N` #2
  - NetworkManager #2 executes its `Awake()`, detects that there already is another NetworkManager, and destroys itself and its GameObject `N` #2
  - `R` now has a Missing reference, as `N` #2 no longer exists

You can verify that this is the problem by setting `LogLevel` on your NetworkManager to "Developer". After returning to the Lobby you should see the following log output in your Console:

```
 Multiple NetworkManagers detected in the scene. Only one NetworkManager can exist at a time. The duplicate NetworkManager will not be used.
```

My solution to this problem usually is not having a NetworkManager in the scene at all, but instantiating it from code on game startup. That way I have full control over its lifetime.